# openBD掲載書誌はどのように決定されているのですか？ ISBNを入力してもNULLが返ることがあるのですが、

Tags: webapi

openBD掲載書誌はどのように決定されているのですか？
ISBNが採番されているのにNULLが返ってきたのですが、考えられる理由としては
・そもそも未収緑
・販売終了したらNULLが返る、ようなルールがある
・上記以外？

結果が返ってくるURL例
https://api.openbd.jp/v1/get?isbn=978-4-7808-0204-7&pretty

NULLが返ってくるURL例
https://api.openbd.jp/v1/get?isbn=4-344-40256-1

試してみたこと
先頭に978_を付与してみましたが、NULLが返ってきました。
https://api.openbd.jp/v1/get?isbn=978_4-344-40256-1

Comment: [openBD](https://openbd.jp/) サイトの「ガイドライン・利用規約」に`不具合の報告や改善の提案は歓迎します。`とあるので問い合わせや連絡をしてみてはどうでしょう？ ちなみにそのISBNは文庫の方で単行本の方(4-344-00061-7)は何か返ってくるようです。

Comment: ISBNは文庫と単行本で異なるのですね、参考になりました

Comment: 該当 web サイト (API) の仕様に関する質問であって、当サイトで扱うプログラミングの質問からは外れるような気がします。